# cyclic references leading to incomplete definition of type 'struct A'

Tags: c

The cyclic reference looks like this. A -> B -> C -> A

I've forward declared A within C to resolve the earlier issue but then IntelliSense is not working or compiler is unable to reach out the fields of A.

**Edit** included guards.

**a.h**

```
#ifndef CYCLIC_A_H
#define CYCLIC_A_H

#include "B.h"

typedef struct A A;

struct A {
    B *b;
    int value;
};

#endif //CYCLIC_A_H
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef CYCLIC_B_H
#define CYCLIC_B_H

#include "C.h"

typedef struct B B;

struct B {
    C *c;
};

#endif //CYCLIC_B_H
```

**c.h**

```
#ifndef CYCLIC_C_H
#define CYCLIC_C_H

// #include "A.h" // this causes issue as well

struct A;

typedef struct C C;

struct C {
    struct A *a;
};

#endif //CYCLIC_C_H
```

main.c

```
#include "C.h"

int main() {
    struct C *c = malloc(sizeof(C));
    c->a->value = 42; // problem

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c.h` should `include` `a.h`.

Comment: Your `main.c` should `#include A.h` rather than `C.h`.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it's not compilable code. Each header needs to have guards. Just include `#include "a.h"` in your main.c Are you setting the value with int type?

Comment: including `A.h` instead of `C.h` worked, but can someone explain please for easier understanding.

Comment: Don't use `typedef` for `struct`, it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `#include "C.h"` incorporates the text from that file (and *only* that file) into the body of the `main.c` file. The trouble then is that there is no **actual definition** of the `A` structure provided.

Now, while you can declare (and even do *some* stuff with) a *pointer* to an undefined structure - so long as you have declared it as a `struct` - (as you have in `C.h`), you cannot access any of that structure's members without the full definition.

So, when you change the header that you `#include`, from `C.h` to `A.h`, the pre-processor inserts the text from that header **and all headers it itself includes** into the body of `main.c`. Thus, the contents of all three headers are thus incorporated, and you then have the full definitions of the `A`, `B` and `C` structures.

*Note: As pointed out in the comments, you also need to complete your "// problem" line, with a proper assignment: `c->a->value = 42; // (or whatever)`.*

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation. Just to play around when I also include `A.h` in `C.h` with or without forward declaration of A, it leads to different errors, just wondering what goes in compiler head or how it sees things?

Comment: When you try to `#include "A.h"` in `C.h`, you get a circular loop, and start redefining your structs. That's where you should use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your headers.

Comment: Oh I get include guards now, I do have them actually, CLion automatically generated them for each file I've, it's just in the code up there but still it has a problem. let me update to include guards.

Comment: Updated, I'm referring to `// #include "A.h" // this causes issue as well` line within `c.h`

Comment: @App Well, it will cause problems if `c.h` was (even indirectly) #included by `A.h` itself - it's like the vacuum cleaner that tries to 'eat' itself.

Comment: @AppDeveloper As it happens, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61622116/10871073) just appeared. Maybe you should follow it?