# C++ redefinition with include guard and #pragma once

Tags: c++

So I'm new to the concept of header files. As far as I understand stuff gets defined in the header and then implemented/used in the *.cpp file. It now cannot build and is giving me Semantic Issues `"redefinition of '//*literally everything*//'"`

What I do now is

```cpp
//move.hpp
#pragma once
#ifndef MOVE_HPP
#define MOVE_HPP

#include <stdio.h>

class Move
{
    private:
        int stolen;

    public:
        Move(int _stolen);
        int get_stolen();
};
#endif /* move_hpp */


//----------------------------------------

//move.cpp
#include "move.hpp"

int Move::get_stolen()
{
    return stolen;
}
Move::Move(int _stolen)
{
    this->stolen = _stolen;
}
```

So what I am doing here is saying what variables and functions Move has, right? Well, I copied my approach more or less from a post describing how to use headers, yet in the move.cpp i get a "Redifinion of 'functionname'" for all of my methods where I give them a body in the *.cpp. So my question is: Am I using headers right and what am I to do to fix the Redefinition error?

edit: when I wrote this I forgot i included this file somwhere else, when I remove that include I don't have any issues but the now used objects that don't exist without the inclide

Comment: Did you include the file move.cpp in some other file?

Comment: Compilers normally give the location of the previous definition. What's the full error message and compilation command?

Comment: @MaritnGe everything is correct in the code you show, it should compile with no issues, is this the only code you have? `#pragma once` is redundant but that shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow previous comment was wrong, overambitious me created the include somewhere else before making the class and then made the class, so i am using it in one other class

Comment: @chris weirdlt when in xcode told me previous definition was at that postions in the .cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you do not need to use `#pragma once` and `#ifndef.. #define... #endif` together. They are the same algorithms for compiling the header file **only once**!
I never encountered the problem myself, but for the purpose of multiplatforming and compiling without errors - I would use the latter (`#ifndef.. and #endif`) only.

About the header, it is written good. The purpose of the header is to declare the class variables and member functions. And, of the .cpp is to define. That is why they are called declaration and definition files, respectively. 
And it seems that you did it right. Only **make sure to include only the .hpp in your main.cpp**, to prevent the redefinition error.

EDIT: Note, if it is of any help, that C++ accepted header files are: .h, .hpp, .hh
and definition types are: .C, .cc, .cpp.

Comment: thank you, i removed the pragma but the build still fails with 'redefinition of 'everything''. in retrospect i failed to mention it in the beginning that this is my issue and will edit accordingly

Comment: Are you including the header or the definition (.cpp) file in the main .cpp?

Comment: @MaritnGe, try to include only the header file to your main.cpp (if you didn't do that already), or try to change the Constructor definition to **stolen = _stolen;**, without **this**. Tell me if it works!

Comment: It worked, including the .hpp did it. if you put this in the answer i will accept this answer. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

the .hpp files are files that are copied by the #include preprocessor instruction. You need to avoid copying it many times (otherwise you would have multiple function definitions, which will lead to compilation issues).

The #pragma once (put this file only once, only works in c++) is equivalent to the #ifndef (if constant not defined, then put the rest of the code), #define (defines it so it would not copy the file a second time) and the #endif (finis of conditional copy)

you can check the output of preprocessor using g++ -E option to stop before compiling, or gcc -E (for c compiling)